# Make the content mobile-keyboard friendly

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, frontend

The content is divided into different sections. I have disabled the vertical direct-scrolling, page can be scrolled using the submit buttons only. Each sections height has been set to 100vh to take up all the available viewport-height. This works great on desktops as well as mobile devices. But, being a form, the problem arises on the mobile devices when you click inside the input boxes and the in-built keyboard pops up. The in-built keyboard takes up almost 50% screen size ant the content (section) is scrolled/moved unusually. Even if the section remains at it place, it is slightly (maybe by 100px) scrolled  up or down if you close the keyboard, making it look ugly. Works good if there's only one section but there will always be more than 10 sections. Is there any other approach to make this successful. I can do this with ajax, but want it to be a single-page (which can be scrolled using those buttons). Or is there any fix available so the content doesnot moves up or down if the mobile keyboard opens or closes?

Thankyou
~Vivek

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo:wght@900&family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+Da+2:wght@800&family=Exo:wght@900&family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap');


*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


:focus {
  outline: none;
}

:root {

  /* Colors */
  --primary: #FF7300;
  --primary-light: #FFE3CC;
  --secondary: #334762;
  --white: #ffffff;

  /* Fonts */
  --font-one: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  --font-two: 'Exo', sans-serif;
  --font-three: 'Baloo Da 2', cursive;
  --font-four: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  --font-five: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

::selection {
  background: var(--white);
  color: var(--primary);
}

body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-color: var(--primary-light);
  font-family: var(--font-four);
  color: var(--secondary);
  font-size: 16px;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  gap: 1.25rem; 
  align-items: center;
}

/* Questions' Wrapper */

.question__wrapper {
  max-width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 1rem;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .question__wrapper {
    gap: .9rem;
  }
}

.container input.text-answer {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  color: var(--primary);
  font-weight:700;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid var(--secondary);
  background-color: var(--bg-color);     
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {   
  .container input.text-answer {
      min-width: unset;
  }
  
}

.small-button-container {
position: absolute;
right: 30px;
bottom: 30px;
}

.small-button {
  font-size: 1.23rem;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--white);
}


.submit-button {
display: block;
max-width: 100px;
border-radius: 3px;
text-align: center;
padding: .4rem .8rem;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: var(--font-three);
background-color: var(--primary);
color: var(--white);
font-size: 1.2rem;
font-weight: 900;
text-decoration: none;

}


@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .submit-button {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>

<body>
    <section id="name">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="logo.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="question__wrapper">
                <div class="question">What is your Name?</div>
                <input type="text" class="text-answer" placeholder="Type here" tabindex="1" required>
                <a href="#email" class="submit-button">Submit</a>
                <div class="small-button-container">
                    <a href="#email" class="small-button">&#129047;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="email">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="logo.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="question__wrapper">
                <div class="question">What is your Email?</div>
                <input type="text" class="text-answer" placeholder="Type here" tabindex="1" required>
                <a href="#cctc" class="submit-button">Submit</a>
                <div class="small-button-container">
                    <a href="#name" class="small-button">&#129045;</a>
                    <a href="#cctc" class="small-button">&#129047;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: NEVER disable vertical scrolling, what is going to happen on a smartwatch, what is going to happen on a super small landscaped device etc.

Comment: This particular app is not meant for those super small devices.